# How to get referenced entity fields from another content type in single node template

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type called "Resources", this is referenced from another content type called "Projects".

I can get simple text fields in my single node--project.html template for example -

```
{{content.field_project_linked_resource[0['#node'].field_resource_title[0].value }}
```

How do I get more complex fields like image and file fields?

This does not work for example -

```
{{node.field_project_linked_resource[0].entity.field_resource_pdf_1.entity.uri.value }}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: thanks this does not explain how to get referenced fields from another content type though.....

Comment: The difference is not between referenced fields and own fields, the difference is between text/number fields and image/link fields: You can access *any* referenced field by the using the `.entity`, but only simple fields like text/numbers/... have a `.value`

Comment: aha thanks, so how would I get the output of this for example? {{node.field_project_linked_resource[0].entity.field_resource_pdf_1.entity.uri.value }}

Comment: I'd recommend to use the `.url` function for link fields, so the schema for normal url would be `{{ entity_type.field_name[0].url }}`. Because your field is owned by a referenced paragraph entity, you must first get the paragraph `{{ host_entity.host_field[0].entity }}`. So the final schema is `{{ host_entity.host_field[0].entity.field_name[0].url }}`